# Trouble trying to make an dynamic list using RXJS

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to create a service worker that will provide me information from API about users.

The idea is that I don't want to make useless requests like asking for the same user twice so I'm trying to implement a function that checks if we have stored the user data and if not to get it from the server.

I tried to use pipes such as  `mapTo`, `share`, `shareReplay`

```js
users = new BehaviorSubject<Array<User>>([]);
```

```js
getUserInfo(id: string) {
 return new Observable((sub) => {
   const users = this.users.getValue();
   let user = users.find((u) => u._id === id);

   if (user) {
     sub.next(user);
     sub.complete();
     return;
   }

   this.api.get('users/' + id, this.userService.getAuthToken(), ).then((data) => {
     user = new User(data, this);
     users.push(user);
     this.users.next(users);
     sub.next(user);
     sub.complete();
   }).catch((err) => {
     sub.error(err);
   });
 });
}
```

So when I call getUser 2 times simultaneously with the same id it should request just once.

Comment: Have a read of an article I wrote on Angular state management with a library I wrote based on behavior subject for this exact use case. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adrian's answer is close, but does not quite answer one part of your question:

> So when I call getUser 2 times simultaneously with the same id it should request just once.

Adrian's solution does not do this, since if the request did not resolve yet the user will not be stored yet and you'll end up requesting the user twice.

Instead the general recommended approach is to store your cache as a map of observables.

Pseudo typescript, syntax might be wrong, I'll also make the assumption that you can turn the api call into an observable, look for Adrian's answer on how to deal with it if not:

```js
users: Map<string,Observable<User>> = new Map();


getUserInfo(id: string): Observable<User> {
  if(!this.users.get(id)){
     const userObservable = this.api.get('users/' + id, this.userService.getAuthToken(), ) // Or turn the promise to observable with `from`
       .pipe(
         map(response => new User(response)),
         share(),
       );
     this.users.set(id, userObservable) 
  }

  return this.users.get(id)

}
```

Comment: Edit: if i call the function in different moments for example 
`for (const id of toLoad) {this.getUserInfo(id).subscribe();}await this.sleep();for (const id of toLoad) {this.getUserInfo(id).subscribe();}`
the method calls again the API

Comment: i used this method but instead of observable i used ReplaySubject I don't know how correct it is to do that but it works. :D. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add a value to an array in a behavior subject you don't mutate the contents of the array, you create a new array and then get the behavior subject to emit that new array.

```
this.users.next([..this.users.value, user]);
```

To create a new observable from a value just use of

```
of(user);
```

Why is your api returning a promise? The http service returns observables so you should be able to just return the http mapped to a user object.

```
return this.api.get('users/' + id, this.userService.getAuthToken(), ).pipe(
  map(functionToMapResponseToAUserObject),
  tap(sideEfectFunctionToInsertNewUserIntoBehaviorSubject)
)
```

So your service could be if you modify your api to return an observable instead of a promise

```
getUserInfo(id: string): Observable<User> {
  const users = this.users.getValue();
  const user = users.find((u) => u._id === id);
  return user
    ? of(user)
    : this.api.get('users/' + id, this.userService.getAuthToken(), ).pipe(
      map(response => new User(response)),
      tap(user => { this.users.next([...users, user]); })
    )
}
```

If you cannot modify the api the use from to convert the promise to an observable

```
from(this.api.get('users/' + id, this.userService.getAuthToken(), ))
```

To stop multiple requests to the same id you would need an object that keeps track of which ones are loading

```
loading: { [key]: Observable<User> } = {};
```

Add a share replay to the api call so the api call will not be repeated and stick it in the loading cache

```
 let loaded = false;
 const user$ = this.api.get('users/' + id, this.userService.getAuthToken(), ).pipe(
    map(response => new User(response)),
    tap(user => {
      this.users.next([...users, user]);
      if (loading[id]) {
        delete loading[id];
      }
      loaded = true;
    }),
    shareReplay()
 );

 if (!loaded) {
   loading[id] = user$;
 }
```

Then you could see if one is loading before firing off an api call and return the observable from the loading cache.

Comment: Does not really answer "So when I call getUser 2 times simultaneously with the same id it should request just once.", good answer nonetheless.

Comment: This code has pretty much the same behavior as what i wrote, just in a much cleaner way.

Comment: I added a cache object to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach, I believe it will satisfy your needs

```
usersSubject = new Subject<User>();
usersCache = this.usersSubject.pipe(
  scan<Record<string, User>>((cache, user) => {
    cache[user.id] = user;
    return cache;
  }, {}),
  shareReplay(1) // keeping the last version of the cache
);


getUserInfo(id: string): Observable<User> {
  return this.usersCache.pipe(
    pluck(id),
    switchMap(user => iif(() => !user,
      this.api.get('users/' + id, this.userService.getAuthToken()).pipe(
        tap(user => this.usersSubject.next(user)) // caching the user
      ),
      of(user)
    ),
    first() // auto unsubscription, because usersCache will keep pushing values
  )
}
```

UPDATE:
Make sure to maintain a subscription open to keep the cache intact (I guess it is a service, so do it in constructor):

```
this.usersCache.subscribe()
```

Comment: Also does not answer "So when I call getUser 2 times simultaneously with the same id it should request just once.".

Comment: yeah, sorry, you should keep a subscription to userCache all the time: 
this.usersCache.subscribe().
If it is a service, do it in constructor; if it's a component, do it in OnInit() method. (I hope it is a service, otherwise you are likely to have a memory leak)

Comment: well now is not even sending any requests. yes it is a service so i added the `this.usersCache.subscribe();` then i ran a test calling the method multiple times and i can't see any requests going on there. i'm not that familiar with RXJS.

Comment: The behavior you are describing is only possible if you are not subscribing to the Observable returned from getUserInfo() method.